# I am not able to print the value by object of the class input taken by the user

Tags: python-3.x

`print(xyz.age)`  #not able to print this

```
class abc:

    def __init__(self):
            pass

    @classmethod   
    def getinput(self):
        self.name = input("enter your name")
        self.age= input("enter your age")
        self.gender = input("enter your gender")
        self.address = input("enter your address")
        print( 'your name is {} and age is {} your are {} and you live at {}'.format(self.name,self.age,self.gender,self.address))

xyz = abc.getinput()
```

`print(xyz.age)`  #not able to print this

Comment: You want to make a class instance so two more parenthesis are needed I think; Try `xyz = abc().getinput()`.

Comment: Also, if you don't know them you might appreciate f-strings. `print(f'your name is {self.name} and age is {self.age} you are {self.gender} and you live at {self.address}')`.

Answer (score 1):

You did not instantiate your class correctly you are just calling one of its methods.
Try this...

```
xyz = abc()
xyz.getinput()
print('Age', xyz.age)
```

Comment: to elaborate on John S's point, a *static* method of `abc` could be being called by the syntax `abc.` while what you want to do is call one of `abc`'s *instance* methods

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

1) xyz is not a instance of your class, it is just storing whatever you are returning from `getinput`(In your case, you are returning `None`).

2) For accessing variables of abc class, you need to create instance like 
`xyz = abc()`. then you can access the attributes of class through xyz instance.